# Basic Authentication and NSURLConnection over 3G

Tags: ios, json, wifi, nsurlconnection, 3g

I am currently working on an iOS app that requires Basic HTTP Authentication to hit web-services.
I developed the networking part using the iOS Simulator and the company WiFi network.

Some of my colleagues tried my app with their own iPads, over 3G network. It appears that what I did to manage the connection is not working properly... I just can't explain why all of my work isn't working with a 3/4G connection.

I tried to see what's happening in the **connectionDidFinishLoading** method.

- With WiFi, the URL I hit gives back a proper JSON file.
- With 3G, I have a sweet (null)

OK, so let's see what's going on in the **didReceiveResponse** method...

With WiFi, I get that :

```
NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x95c7130 { URL: URL_giving_json} { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 15 Jan 2014 15:33:05 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15";
    Server = "JAS BHV3";
    "Set-Cookie" = "SMSESSION=cookie; Path=/appname/; HttpOnly, ASID=.a1s1; path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity; } }
```

With 3G, I get that :

```
NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x97d8530 { URL: Connection_URL&TARGET=URL_giving_json} { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 3296;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    Date = "Wed, 15 Jan 2014 15:28:05 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }
```

Here's what I tried :

```
- (void)hitURLWithURLString:(NSString *)URLToHit
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLToHit];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        // 1 - Received authentication challenge
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.login
                                                                    password:self.password
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        // 2 - Credential created
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        // 3 - Responded to authentication challenge
    }
    else
    {
        // 1 - Previous authentication failure
        [self.delegate authenticationDidFail:self];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self.delegate didFinishLoading:self fulldata:self.receivedData];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"--->Finished : %@", [dictionary description]); // gives (null) here
    connection = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed ! Error - %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    [self.delegate didFailWithError:self error:error];
}
```

Does anyone know something about this issue ? Why can't I get my JSON with a 3G connected device ?

Thank you so much for your help.

And please, excuse my English, I'm French... :)

Comment: First hint: You should setup the request including an "Accept" header: `Accept: application/json`. You can read the `NSMutableURLRequest` docs to see how to accomplish this. If you fixed that, please try again.

Comment: I tried your guess, but the issue doesn't come from here. Using internet, I can't go through the connection level... Using intranet, there's nothing to worry about. Am I missing something ?

Comment: On 3G, is the service again returning a "text/html" MIME type and status code 200 (OK)? This indicates a flawed service. It may be the case something happens in between, e.g. a service provider sending you a 200 (OK) and a html message: "Hey, this page is not available - try later again." or something similar. Usually, you shouldn't get a 200 (OK) if the server cannot send you the resource which you requested. You may print / render the html and check what it says.

Comment: On 3G (and on WiFi, and on Ethernet), if I go to the URL which is giving JSON, I am redirected to the http://Connection_URL&TARGET=URL_giving_json and I have a form to fulfill with my credentials to access to the JSON.

Comment: For a web API where the client is an app (as opposed to a browser), if the service requires credentials, it should not redirect you to a login page which is presented via a html form. Instead, it should respond with 401 (Unauthorized). Then, the URL loading scheme will work in a way for which you implemented the delegates. Otherwise, dealing with a form is difficult - up to impossible: you may try to provide the credentials in the URL.

Comment: I do agree with you, but why does it work using the company WiFi, and it doesn't work using 3G. It is exactly the same code running in both cases... I think I forgot something dealing with security in the request or the connection, but I have no idea of what I am missing.

Comment: hi. i'm facing the same. you got anything to fix this up?

Comment: Hi Raj, I fixed this up modifying the authent method server-side. Using an external network, I faced an HTML form. Using an internal network, I faced a basic authent (with a popup). It was a line to modify from the server... Hope it helps... :/ Cheers.